# Beamer: Highlight all subsections in Table of Contents

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

```
\section{Section Title}
\frame{\tableofcontents[currentsection]}
\subsection{Subsection Title}
```

I use the above command to insert a table of contents at the beginning of each section with the current section highlighted.
Can I highlight all subsection titles under the current section?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  \tableofcontents[currentsection,subsectionstyle=show/show/shaded]
```

I found the answer in the Beamer manual.